# Hide an option in a spinner

Tags: java, android

So I'm creating currency converting app on android I have two spinners and I'm trying to hide option from the second spinner when that option is already selected by the first spinner, like if i choose to convert from USD the second spinner USD option should disappear but I just don't have any idea how to hide an option I searched on google most question asks about hiding the whole spinner not option

```
    package com.currencyconverter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.amountToBeConvert;
import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.currencies;
import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.currencyFrom;
import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.currencyTo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button btn;
    public EditText et_AmountToBeConverted;
    public Spinner sp_CurrencyFrom;
    public Spinner sp_CurrencyTo;
    public TextView tv_ConvertedAmount;
    public TextView tv_ConvertedCurrency;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declaring XML
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        et_AmountToBeConverted = findViewById(R.id.et_AmountToBeConverted);
        sp_CurrencyFrom = findViewById(R.id.sp_CurrencyFrom);
        sp_CurrencyTo = findViewById(R.id.sp_CurrencyTo);
        tv_ConvertedAmount = findViewById(R.id.tv_ConvertedAmount);
        tv_ConvertedCurrency = findViewById(R.id.tv_ConvertedCurrency);


        // Database work
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rates");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);



        //Inserting string to spinners
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currencies);
        sp_CurrencyTo.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp_CurrencyFrom.setAdapter(adapter);




        //Spinner onseclectlistener
        sp_CurrencyFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                currencyFrom = i;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        sp_CurrencyTo.getItemAtPosition((int) sp_CurrencyFrom.getSelectedItemId()).setEnabled(false);

        sp_CurrencyTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                currencyTo = i;



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });









        //Convert!!
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Convert XML to data
                amountToBeConvert = Double.parseDouble(et_AmountToBeConverted.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

globalData

```
    package com.currencyconverter;

public class globalData {
    public static String[] currencies = {"AED", "AFN", "ALL", "AMD", "ANG", "AOA", "ARS", "AUD", "AWG", "AZN", "BAM", "BBD", "BDT", "BGN", "BHD", "BIF", "BMD", "BND", "BOB", "BRL", "BSD", "BTC", "BTN", "BWP", "BYN", "BYR", "BZD", "CAD", "CDF", "CHF", "CLF", "CLP", "CNY", "COP", "CRC", "CUC", "CUP", "CVE", "CZK", "DJF", "DKK", "DOP", "DZD", "EGP", "ERN", "ETB", "EUR", "FJD", "FKP", "GBP", "GEL", "GGP", "GHS", "GIP", "GMD", "GNF", "GTQ", "GYD", "HKD", "HNL", "HRK", "HTG", "HUF", "IDR", "ILS", "IMP", "INR", "IQD", "IRR", "ISK", "JEP", "JMD", "JOD", "JPY", "KES", "KGS", "KHR", "KMF", "KPW", "KRW", "KWD", "KYD", "KZT", "LAK", "LBP", "LKR", "LRD", "LSL", "LTL", "LVL", "LYD", "MAD", "MDL", "MGA", "MKD", "MMK", "MNT", "MOP", "MRO", "MUR", "MVR", "MWK", "MXN", "MYR", "MZN", "NAD", "NGN", "NIO", "NOK", "NPR", "NZD", "OMR", "PAB", "PEN", "PGK", "PHP", "PKR", "PLN", "PYG", "QAR", "RON", "RSD", "RUB", "RWF", "SAR", "SBD", "SCR", "SDG", "SEK", "SGD", "SHP", "SLL", "SOS", "SRD", "STD", "SVC", "SYP", "SZL", "THB", "TJS", "TMT", "TND", "TOP", "TRY", "TTD", "TWD", "TZS", "UAH", "UGX", "UYU", "UZS", "VEF", "VND", "VUV", "WST", "XAF", "XAG", "XAU", "XCD", "XDR", "XOF", "XPF", "YER", "ZAR", "ZMK", "ZMW", "ZWL" };
    public static double rate;
    public static double amountToBeConvert;
    public static int currencyFrom;
    public static int currencyTo;
    public static String[] currencies2 = {"AED", "AFN", "ALL", "AMD", "ANG", "AOA", "ARS", "AUD", "AWG", "AZN", "BAM", "BBD", "BDT", "BGN", "BHD", "BIF", "BMD", "BND", "BOB", "BRL", "BSD", "BTC", "BTN", "BWP", "BYN", "BYR", "BZD", "CAD", "CDF", "CHF", "CLF", "CLP", "CNY", "COP", "CRC", "CUC", "CUP", "CVE", "CZK", "DJF", "DKK", "DOP", "DZD", "EGP", "ERN", "ETB", "EUR", "FJD", "FKP", "GBP", "GEL", "GGP", "GHS", "GIP", "GMD", "GNF", "GTQ", "GYD", "HKD", "HNL", "HRK", "HTG", "HUF", "IDR", "ILS", "IMP", "INR", "IQD", "IRR", "ISK", "JEP", "JMD", "JOD", "JPY", "KES", "KGS", "KHR", "KMF", "KPW", "KRW", "KWD", "KYD", "KZT", "LAK", "LBP", "LKR", "LRD", "LSL", "LTL", "LVL", "LYD", "MAD", "MDL", "MGA", "MKD", "MMK", "MNT", "MOP", "MRO", "MUR", "MVR", "MWK", "MXN", "MYR", "MZN", "NAD", "NGN", "NIO", "NOK", "NPR", "NZD", "OMR", "PAB", "PEN", "PGK", "PHP", "PKR", "PLN", "PYG", "QAR", "RON", "RSD", "RUB", "RWF", "SAR", "SBD", "SCR", "SDG", "SEK", "SGD", "SHP", "SLL", "SOS", "SRD", "STD", "SVC", "SYP", "SZL", "THB", "TJS", "TMT", "TND", "TOP", "TRY", "TTD", "TWD", "TZS", "UAH", "UGX", "UYU", "UZS", "VEF", "VND", "VUV", "WST", "XAF", "XAG", "XAU", "XCD", "XDR", "XOF", "XPF", "YER", "ZAR", "ZMK", "ZMW", "ZWL" };
}
```

EDIT:

```
    package com.currencyconverter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.amountToBeConvert;
import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.currencies;
import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.currencies2;
import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.currencyFrom;
import static com.currencyconverter.globalData.currencyTo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button btn;
    public EditText et_AmountToBeConverted;
    public Spinner sp_CurrencyFrom;
    public Spinner sp_CurrencyTo;
    public TextView tv_ConvertedAmount;
    public TextView tv_ConvertedCurrency;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declaring XML
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        et_AmountToBeConverted = findViewById(R.id.et_AmountToBeConverted);
        sp_CurrencyFrom = findViewById(R.id.sp_CurrencyFrom);
        sp_CurrencyTo = findViewById(R.id.sp_CurrencyTo);
        tv_ConvertedAmount = findViewById(R.id.tv_ConvertedAmount);
        tv_ConvertedCurrency = findViewById(R.id.tv_ConvertedCurrency);


        // Database work
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("quotes");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);



        //Inserting string to spinners
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currencies);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currencies2);
        sp_CurrencyTo.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp_CurrencyFrom.setAdapter(adapter2);




        //Spinner onseclectlistener
        sp_CurrencyFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                currencyFrom = i;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        adapter2.remove(currencies2[sp_CurrencyFrom.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

        sp_CurrencyTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                currencyTo = i;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });









        //Convert!!
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Convert XML to data
                amountToBeConvert = Double.parseDouble(et_AmountToBeConverted.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When first spinner gets selected, remove that string from second array adapter.

Comment: i.e in OnItemSelected listner of first spinner. Remove that entry from second adapter (make it member variable of class) by calling adapter.remove(String)

Comment: Just use different adapters for the 2 spinners (although they're populated with the same items) and remove the item you want from the 2nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove items from the arrays you use for your adapters. 
Declare them like this:

```
ArrayList<String> currencies = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("AED", "AFN", "ALL", .......));
```

Now you use ArrayList and you can remove items.

Comment: I edited the class, now its two adapters but remove function is crashing the app

Comment: Read my answer, the solution with 2 adapters is very complicated

Comment: Sorry but I just started learning java my main question was how do I remove an option on (repopulate) `currencies` array.

Comment: Do `currencies.remove(index);` where `index` is the position of the item to be removed and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to refresh the data in your spinner.

Comment: Can't use `currencies.remove(index);` its writing me error I should use `adapter.remove(index);` and that line crashes the app.

Comment: Of course  you must have 2 separate lists for currencies to attach to the 2 adapters.

Comment: I did make 2 arrays and 2 adapters check the edited class

Comment: Post the `globalData` class

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: I' m glad, be well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can set an action listener on the first spinner which will set items on the second spinner

    /*Dynamic spinner adapters*/
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int n, long n2) {
            switch (adapterView.getId()) {
                case R.id.firstspinner: {
                    ArrayList<String> allItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
    String selected = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.firstspinner)).getSelectedItem().toString());

    Integer index = allItems.indexOf(selected);
    allItems.remove(index);

                    ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.secondspinner)).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinresoc, allItems) {
                        public View getDropDownView(int n, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(n, view, viewGroup);
                            textView.setTextSize((float)  15.0f);
                            return textView;
                        }

                        public View getView(int n, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(n, view, viewGroup);
                            textView.setTextSize((float) 15.0f);
                            return textView;
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

/*XML resource R.layout.spinresoc*/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:background="@drawable/spinbacro"
    android:paddingTop="10.0dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
    android:textColor="#ff1a1a1a" />
```